# How can I create an array with Fibonacci numbers up to a certain integer n?

Tags: c++, arrays, fibonacci

So for an assignment I've been asked to create a function that will generate an array of fibonacci numbers and the user will then provide an array of random numbers. My function must then check if the array the user has entered contains any fibonacci numbers then the function will output true, otherwise it will output false. I have already been able to create the array of Fib numbers and check it against the array that the user enters however it is limited since my Fib array has a max size of 100.

```
bool hasFibNum (int arr[], int size){

int fibarray[100];
fibarray[0] = 0;
fibarray[1] = 1;
bool result = false;
for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++)
{
    fibarray[i] = fibarray[i-1] + fibarray[i-2];

}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
        if (fibarray[j] == arr[i])
            result = true;
    }
}

return result;
}
```

So basically how can I make it so that I don't have to use int fibarray[100] and can instead generate fib numbers up to a certain point. That point being the maximum number in the user's array.

So for example if the user enters the array {4,2,1,8,21}, I need to generate a fibarray up to the number 21 {1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21}. If the user enters the array {1,4,10} I would need to generate a fibarray with {1,1,2,3,5,8,13}

Quite new to programming so any help would be appreciated! Sorry if my code is terrible.

Comment: Loop through the user's array to find the max number, then create fib numbers up to that number. Is this sort of the solution youre asking for? I'm having trouble understanding your question

Comment: Yes, sorry if my wording made it a bit complicated to understand. But that's pretty much what I need to do.

Comment: Don't you mean if the user enters `{1, 4, 10}` you would have to generate a fib array up to `10`, since `10` is the largest? Your array goes up to `13` when I assumed it would've gone up to `8`.

Comment: Well 10 is not a fibonacci number, the second array that is being generated is an array of fibonacci numbers. {1,4,10} <-- User array and {1,1,2,3,5,8,13} <-- Fibonacci array

Comment: Instead of a static array, use a vector, to which you can append as many elements as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that I still don't understand your question, but if I do, then I would achieve what you want like this:

```
bool hasFibNum (int arr[], int size){
    if (size == 0) return false;
    int maxValue = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > maxValue) maxValue = arr[i];
    }
    int first = 0;
    int second = 1;
    while (second < maxValue)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == first) return true;
            if (arr[i] == second) return true;
        }
        first = first + second;
        second = second + first;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: We are only allowed to use <iostream>. There are probably dozens of other ways to do this much more efficiently but we haven't been introduced to the vector library yet.

Comment: Yes! This is perfect! Thank you very much for your help it's very much appreciated. Hope I can return the favor somehow.

Comment: This is `O(n * lg n)`, which I guess isn't bad. (fibs grow exponentially)  Can make it faster by inverting that bottom loop (for each value, check each fib, instead of check each value for each fib) via improved memory locality, if you care about that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that returns a dynamic array with all of the Fibonacci numbers up to and including `max` (assuming `max > 0`)

```
std::vector<size_t> make_fibs( size_t max ) {
  std::vector<size_t> retval = {1,1};
  while( retval.back() < max ) {
    retval.push_back( retval.back()+*(retval.end()-2) );
  }
  return retval;
}
```

I prepopulate it with 2 elements rather than keeping track of the last 2 separately.

Note that under some definitions, `0` and `-1` are Fibonacci numbers.  If you are using that, start the array off with `{-1, 0, 1}` (which isn't their order, it is actually `-1, 1, 0, 1`, but by keeping them in ascending order we can `binary_search` below).  If you do so, change the type to an `int` not a `size_t`.

Next, a sketch of an implementation for `has_fibs`:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
bool has_fibs( T(&array)[N] ) {
  // bring `begin` and `end` into view, one of the good uses of `using`:
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  // guaranteed array is nonempty, so 
  T m = *std::max_element( begin(array), end(array) ); will have a max, so * is safe.
  if (m < 0) m = 0; // deal with the possibility the `array` is all negative

  // use `auto` to not repeat a type, and `const` because we aren't going to alter it:
  const auto fibs = make_fibs(m);

  // d-d-d-ouble `std` algorithm:
  return std::find_if( begin(array), end(array), [&fibs]( T v )->bool {
    return std::binary_search( begin(fibs), end(fibs), v );
  }) != end(array);
}
```

here I create a template function that takes your (fixed sized) array as a reference.  This has the advantage that ranged-based loops will work on it.

Next, I use a `std` algorithm `max_element` to find the max element.

Finally, I use two `std` algorithms, `find_if` and `binary_search`, plus a lambda to glue them together, to find any intersections between the two containers.

I'm liberally using C++11 features and lots of abstraction here.  If you don't understand a function, I encourage you to rewrite the parts you don't understand rather than copying blindly.

This code has runtime `O(n lg lg n)` which is probably overkill.  (fibs grow exponentially.  Building them takes `lg n` time, searching them takes `lg lg n` time, and we search then `n` times).